# Docker + GNU Screen lags

Tags: docker, gnu-screen

Struggling with GNU Screen inside docker environment.

Near all utils are working with glitches. Top, mc or nano can show this kind of problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBuG8.png

Lines are shifted and destructed. Is it possible to overcome?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a host OS and same Ubuntu 14.04 as a container image. Running docker 1.8.1 and screen from default package.

How to reproduce:

```
# Prepare container with ubuntu

sudo docker pull ubuntu
sudo docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash

# Installing GNU Screen in running container

apt-get update
apt-get install screen

# Entering screen

screen

# How to see glitches:
# 1. Inside first window launch top

top

# 2. Create new window with Ctrl-a c
# 3. Switch to previous window with Ctrl-a a
# Glitches apper on the screen as in provided screenshot
```

This is the screen of mc with glitches:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaerV.png

How to reproduce:

```
# Install mc in container

apt-get install mc

# Run screen if its not running

screen

# Enter mc

mc

# Go down the list with down-arrow key
# Glitches apper
```

How to reproduce bugs in nano:

```
# Install nano and wget

apt-get nano wget

# Download and open file in nano

cd
wget -O docker.html 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)'
nano docker.html

# Navigate  in file using only arrow keys and you will be surprised
# how text become unreadable
```

Comment: In your  container, `echo $TERM`?

Comment: TERM is xterm. And I can start screen normally. But glitches.

Comment: Do you have a reproducer, Dockerfile, `docker run` command?

Comment: sure! i've updated my description

Comment: I reproduce your problem,  with latest docker 1.8.1, build Git commit:   d12ea79

Comment: some people use heavily screen with no problem it seems https://blog.raintank.io/docker-based-development-environment/

Comment: I also so other articles when I was searching for any solution. Along with glitches I cannot reattach screen session.

Comment: I commit a container with screen installed, then I `docker run -i -t ... sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -s /bin/bash"` and now, screen top shows the glitches, but if I type return, I am back with a correct display

Comment: I've also reproduced glitches with your command.

Comment: yes but when I hit Return once, it is correct then

Comment: If you would spend some time you will see glitches all around. Its totally unusable because you can't read important output. Also you cant edit some documents etc.